# How to fetch datas from multiple table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have three different tables, let's name them as

table1,
table2,
table3

But in these different tables, I have the same number of columns and also the same name. For example,

- Table 1 columns: id, title, category, subcategory, image
- Table 2 columns: id, title, category, subcategory, image
- Table 3 columns: id, title, category, subcategory, image

How can I fetch all those 3 tables using a single foreach?

```php
function post_details(){
  global $db;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY id DESC";
  $run_query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  $post_details = mysqli_fetch_all($run_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $getdetails = array();
  
  foreach ($post_details as $post_detail) {
    array_push($getdetails, $post_detail);
  }

  return $getdetails;
}
```

Comment: _Why_ do you have multiple tables of the exact same structure to begin with? That is a very strong indicator, that most likely all your data should be contained in _one_ single table in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you page shows blank,add this on top of php file

```php
//if error happend,this will display error on page
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

you can use `mysql union` if you want simple loop the rows

```php
function post_details(){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts1 WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $query .= " UNION SELECT * FROM posts2 WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $query .= " UNION SELECT * FROM posts3 WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $post_details = mysqli_fetch_all($run_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $getdetails = array();
    
  foreach ($post_details as $post_detail) {
        array_push($getdetails, $post_detail);
    }

    return $getdetails;
}
```

if you want order by all table you can use temporary table like this,be careful of this,it could be slow in large dataset,due to it sort on temporary table.

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM posts1 WHERE status = 'Active'  
                UNION SELECT * FROM posts2 WHERE status = 'Active' 
                UNION SELECT * FROM posts3 WHERE status = 'Active') 
            AS t1 ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: How do i run multiple queries that you've mentioned ?

Comment: you do not need to run multi `mysqli_query`,I had combine all result in one `SQL`,did you try my code?

Comment: After using this code my out output page becomes blank i don't know why.

Comment: maybe there has some sql syntax error,did you change the table name in the sql?I have update my answer,paste the code to the php,it will print out the error message

Comment: What's the purpose of the `foreach` loop?

Comment: It's Working Thanks Nay and Vishal P Gothi, I have one issue how can i order all 3 tables union ? The one i've used for seperately right it just ordering for it's own table alone. I want to show the latest of 3 tables in front using order by id desc. How can i do that ?

Comment: hi @harish,I have update my answer for order all table

Answer (score 1):

Actually when we want to fetch records from the multiple table with the same columns or from the same table and different conditions, then we need to use UNION to merge all those records in the same SQL Query so please use this query and replace the table name with your real table names.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ( ( SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY id DESC ) 
UNION 
( SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY id DESC ) 
UNION 
( SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE status = 'Active' ORDER BY id DESC ) ) as tempdata";
```